# .equals method returns false even if the contents of the strings are the same

Tags: java, android

So I was trying to compare the system time with the time entered in a Time Picker

To do this I placed the system time within a string which is the variable cTime and the time entered from the Time Picker which is in the variable eTime.

Before doing this, I first formatted the system time with the pattern "HH:mm" and place a ":" before the hour and minute in eTime.

Here is my codes.

```
    Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    cTime =  currentTime.format(now);
    eTime = String.valueOf(endTime.getCurrentHour()) + ":" + 
    String.valueOf(endTime.getCurrentMinute());

    if(eTime.length() == 1) {
     eTime = "0" + eTime;
    }

    if(eTime.equals(cTime)) {
     String message = "Please select time properly";
     warnUser(message);
     return;
    }
```

After doing some checkings I found that the .equals method in the if statement returns false.

Comment: Check the format of both eTime and cTime

Comment: I tried using a toast to show the contents of cTime and eTime and found out that they are the same still it returns false

Comment: what was the format of endTime

Comment: `eTime` could be something like `1:1` while `cTime` could never be `01:01`.

Comment: Use Date instead of string eTime, and cTime, or compare with equalignorecase it will works.

Comment: `eTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", endTime.getCurrentHour(), endTime.getCurrentMinute());` and probably more.

Answer (score 0):

normally .equals compare two object contents correctly, I 've already use it so many times with String type, so please check if the input of cTime and eTime is correct, may be there is some additional space or '\n' character.

Comment: thanks for the advice I tried to remove all the "\n" with .removeAll method.

Comment: it now returns true however if the eTime is changed it still returns true

Comment: As I said try to check you entire code, equals method should work fine in comparing Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use Date instead of string eTime, and cTime, or compare with equalignorecase it will works.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some code inspection I found out that I added an extra space before the current time and became something like this " 17:23" and after I removed that space it now works. Thanks for the help